# Weird return url

Tags: c#, php, .net, http, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use `oauth2`.

I make a get request, and then I get redirected at a callback url that I have set up before. The problem lies in the fact that the url parameters get preceded by the `#` sign and thus `php`, `.net` can't read them!

I get redirected in the following url in my browser:

> http://localhost:1787/About.aspx?#access_token=f3EToovT2bQNNOQ&token_type=bearer&merchant_id=A6BGD4BH&response_type=token

`Request.Params` is empty, `request.query string` is empty. Even when I use php and print the `$_REQUEST` array still is empty!

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever comes after the `#` doesn't mark as DATA being sent to the server, but a hash on the client side.

Try redirect using **JavaScript** only the hash:

```
window.location = window.location.pathname + '?' + window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Comment: This url is redirected from the oath2 page, isn't created by me... I just want to read the get parameters that I get back. How should I proceed in this case? I first redirect to oauth2page with my parameters and i get redirected back to the url that i showed you with the # symbol

Comment: Than you should do it using JavaScript, with it you can build the redirect by using the anchor information.